# why doesn't it get if statement scope

Tags: java, if-statement, foreach

```
int[] array = { 1, 2, 4, 5 };
for (int element : array) {
    System.out.println(element % 2); // it is calculate
    if (element % 2 == 0) { // but it is not calculate
        element--;
    }
}

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

Does the output need to be *[1 1 3 5]* like this?

Comment: You'll need to use an old-fashioned loop using index. That allows you to change the value of `array[i`].

Comment: And this isn't a "scope" issue at all